# Is during also an adverb?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> People often focus on a quake’s magnitude, a measure of the size of, and to an extent the energy released **during**, the rupture in Earth’s surface.  [What made the earthquake in Morocco so devastating](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/what-made-the-earthquake-in-morocco-so-devastating)

Does the during serve as an adverb? Also, why is there no and between the extent of energy released and the rupture in Earth’s surface?

Comment: Your sentence was incorrectly parsed.

Comment: It's a poorly written sentence. "People often focus on a quake’s magnitude, a measure of [the size of], [and to an extent the energy released during], the rupture in **the** Earth’s surface". The bracketed elements are a coordination of two NPs functioning as object of the preposition "of".

Answer (score 6):

During is a preposition, applied to "the rupture ..." in this case, meaning "in the course of".

Magnitude is a measure of the size of the rupture and magnitude is a measure of the energy released during the rupture.